# Problem About HTML Code Created By Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html, datagrid

I have a javascript function which get datagrid's header into THEAD tags. This code triggered on body onload event and run correctly.

However, when i look to view source, i can't see these dynamicly generated codes. I want to see it there. How can I do it?

```
function AddTHEAD(tableName)
{
   var table = document.getElementById(tableName); 
   if(table != null) 
   {
    var head = document.createElement("THEAD");
    head.style.display = "table-header-group";
    head.appendChild(table.rows[0]);
    table.insertBefore(head, table.childNodes[0]); 
   }
}
```

**Edit:** I want to talk about why I need this:
With the function above, I want Datagrid's header to be shown on every page when I print the page.

For this purpose I have css code below. When I add THEAD tag manually, it works fine. But when it's created by Javascript, it's seen on print preview but not on real printing.

```
    tHead
   {
    display : table-header-group;
   }
```

**Edit2:** I found a clue. When I firstly open print preview page and then click the print button there, it works. But when I directly clik the print button which run window.print javascript code, it don't works. Can anyone has a solution about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to see javascript-generated code with 'view source'. This is because you are viewing the source generated by the webserver, and the HTML code you're looking for is generated by client-side javascript, after the webserver has served the HTML.

If you want to see the code generated by javascript, install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, and use the "Inspect Element" feature (right click on an element on the screen).

Comment: This can also be done natively in recent copies of Chrome and Safari (though Safari requires that the Web Inspector be enabled)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my question for explaining my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The source is now available in variable `source`.

```
var source = document.getElementById(tableName).innerHTML;
// show the source
alert(source);
```